# Change color space of image texture node using python?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, image

I have trouble to get a script working within *Blender 2.8*. What is the correct way to change **Color Space** mode of an image texture node?

```
node_opacity = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeTexImage")
node_opacity.colorspace_settings.name = "Linear"
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The colorspace is shown from the image data, it is not a node property.

```
node_opacity.image.colorspace_settings.name = 'Linear'
```

Comment: Wow..  I wouldn't expect to have to reach for the string value of its name..

Comment: @RobinBetts despite the name, it is an enum. Will throw an error if you set it willy nilly `enum "willynilly" not found in ('Filmic Log', 'Linear', 'Linear ACES', 'Non-Color', 'Raw', 'sRGB', 'XYZ')`

Comment: Thank you for the command, but when I set the image to Linear my normal map baked becomes black it loses all his informations.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to reference it with the node property, you can do

```
bpy.data.materials[0].node_tree.nodes['Image Texture'].image.colorspace_settings.name='Linear'
```